# Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Found duplicate FunctionMetadata with the name XXX

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I published Azure Functions, and I'm getting this error message.

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Found duplicate FunctionMetadata with
> the name XXX.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error when I was renaming couple of project (one for demo and other with actual function - both had same function name) to fit to internal naming conventions. However, after cleaning both the solutions and then trying again worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

What caught me out with this is that the "name" is the string provided in the `FunctionAtrribute`. Not the function name itself. So this code causes the error:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Found duplicate FunctionMetadata with the name MyFunction

```cs
[Function("MyFunction")]
public void MyFunction() {}

[Function("MyFunction")]
public void MyOtherFunction() {}
```

Note the duplicated `[Function("MyFunction")]`.

---

Also worth noting that when I looked at the list of functions in Azure the error I got was:

> azure functions runtime is unreachable

the duplicate error is only visible in the log stream or in the Activity Log

Answer (score -1):

It is because I had two functions that had the same name.

Changing the name resolved this error.